# Make Joomla component compatible with SEF/SEO

Tags: php, seo, joomla, components, joomla-sef-urls

Hi I have developed a custom component for Joomla 1.5. However the urls when SEF is turned on could look a bit better e.g. display the title rather than the id, how can I make custom urls for my component when SEF for Joomla is turned on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked in to the Joomla routing methods?  http://docs.joomla.org/Routing

Answer (score 1):

You Can use JRoute class as follows:

```
JRoute::_( $url, $xhtml = true, $ssl=null );
```

**$url** is a string containing the absolute or relative internal Joomla! URL.

**$xhtml** is a boolean value that specifies whether or not the output should be in XHTML. This parameter is optional and if omitted defaults to true.

**$ssl** is an integer value that specifies whether the URI should be secure. It should be set to 1 to force the URI to be secure using the global secure site URI, 0 to leave it in the same state as when it was passed, and -1 to force the URI to be unsecure using the global unsecure site URI.

The most important parameter is **$url**. A call to this method might look like:

```
JRoute::_( 'index.php?view=article&id='.$[itemID] );
```